# Can use Webform for add combobox for select language on the site?

Tags: blocks

I want to know how I can add a combobox to a page. For example, on the front page, I want to add a combobox for selecting the language. I use the default modules for creating multilingual sites. Languages ​​are displayed as a list on the page. I want to display a combobox instead of the extended list.

Can I do this with the Webform module?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this with webform. Webform's purpose is to collect and store user submitted data.

You can create a language dropdown by creating an override template for `links--language-block.html.twig` in your custom theme.

Comment: How to make it?